# Getting the Memory statistics for a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

I'd just like to ask if there's a way to get the memory statistics of a thread (i.e. Working Set, Private Memory, etc.).  I know that we can obtain those for a Process, but my app needs to run a set of tests and for each test, I need to get the stats, especially the Peak Memory.  Right now the only way I do this is run the app for each test and get the Peak Memory of the process.

Is there perhaps a way to get thread-level memory stats?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads don't *have* memory statistics.

Heap memory is not associated with any single thread.
The information you're looking for does not make sense.

Comment: Not quite true, there's [ThreadStatic] memory.  But close enough.

Comment: @Hans: Not quite.  The memory consumed by an object in a `[ThreadStatic]` field is not associated with any thread.  (A reference or value type is, though)

Comment: Well, sure it is.  It doesn't get garbage collected until the thread terminates.

Comment: @Hans: It's _referenced_ by the thread, but it's not associated with the thread.  You can put the same object into a `[ThreadStatic]` field in two different threads, if you want to.

Comment: Wouldn't you say that the stack space is associated with the thread?

Comment: @Brian: That's constant (1MB per thread, I believe), and not very relevant in .Net.  The OP is asking about heap.

Comment: @SLaks: Right and I agree, but you did say that memory is not associated with any single thread. Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: @Brian: You're right; thanks.  Don't apologize; I enjoy nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

As the other responders suggest, you cannot get memory stats on a by-thread basis. Your best bet would be to either:

1. Run in app-domain and use [App domain resource monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997285.aspx)
2. Run in separate process and use properties on  : System.Diagnostics.Process (for the running process).